# Flutter BLOC Equatable | exception for some variable

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

how to to exclude some variable member in the equatable class to not to be compared ?

```
class MyBlocState extends Equatable {

  LocationPermission locationPermission;
  final LatLng position;

  NavigationState({

    this.locationPermission,
    this.position,
});

MyBlocState copyWith({
  LocationPermission locationPermission,
  LatLng position
}) {
 locationPermission : locationPermission ?? this. locationPermission,
 position : position ?? this. position
}

@override
List<object> get props => [
 locationPermission,
 position
];
```

i want variable position to be checked for equality but not for locationPermission, so in the state widget it still can return the state even though the result is the same, because i need to catch user response even if they give the same response

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `locationPermission` from `get props`.

```
class MyBlocState extends Equatable {

  LocationPermission locationPermission;
  final LatLng position;

  NavigationState({

    this.locationPermission,
    this.position,
});

MyBlocState copyWith({
  LocationPermission locationPermission,
  LatLng position
}) {
 locationPermission : locationPermission ?? this. locationPermission,
 position : position ?? this. position
}

@override
List<object> get props => [
 position
];
```

Comment: the state still not update, it's not work